# SAS appending monthly incremental datasets into one dataset

Tags: sas

I have 6 monthly datasets for each month of this year and every month a new dataset gets added. I need a macro to automatically append the incremental dataset into the existing dataset

(created by appending the 6 existing datasets)

and so on going forward every month. The datasets have exactly the same variables in order and the names are like:

```
'completeextract8634.sas7bdat'
'completeextract8640.sas7bdat'
```

and so on.
Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried ? What folder are the new extracts in ? What folder is the base (permanent and growing) data set in ? Do the data sets contain at least one variable (or column) that specifically identifies an extract ?

Comment: Hi Richard, the base dataset is completeextract8634. The others ending with 8640, 8642 will be appended to it. I have tried a simple proc append, however, it does not help in automatically considering the incremental dataset for the next month for appending. Yes, there is one variable called 'cra_id' that is actually a four digit id corresponding to the figures at the end of the dataset name. For example, for dataset 'completeextract8634', the cra_id will have the unique value of 8634.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you have incremental datasets?  Or do you have cumulative datasets and the problem is you want to identify the new records in completeextract8640 and append only those new records to completeextract8634?  Suggest you add to your question an example with two or three datasets, each with 5-10 records, show your proc append code, and show the output you would want.

Comment: you can use `proc append` inside a macro, and pass the file to be appended everytime a new file comes.

Answer (score 2):

One approach may be to stack the data using a `SET` statement with the data sets to stack being specified with a wildcard (`:`). The wildcard is also known as *shortcut naming* or formally as a ["Data Set List"](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003040446.htm)

**Example DATA step view**

```
DATA work.combined / view=work.combined;
  SET EXTRACT.completeextract: ;
RUN;
```

`Proc APPEND` is also perfect for this.  See the documentation discussion [Concatenating Data Sets By Using the APPEND Procedure](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=basess&docsetTarget=p0zo0l1za54nmpn1q379w70ppxkn.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

**Example macro**

Note: This example presumes your 'system' is setup to manage the appended extracts by allowing them to be moved to a different library.  If a file is not moved, and the *growing* table does not have a unique index, you could end up appending an extract more than once.

```
LIBNAME EXTRACT '<folder containing extract data sets>';
LIBNAME HISTORY '<folder containing the permanent and growing data set>';
LIBNAME DONE    '<folder where extract data sets can be moved to>';

%macro appendFromLib(base=, fromLIb=, dataNamesLike=, doneLib=);
  proc sql;
    %if %sysfunc(exist(work.dataNames)) %then %do;
    drop table dataNames;
    %end;
    create table dataNames as select
    memname from dictionary.tables
    where libname = "%upcase(&fromLib)"
      and memname like %upcase(&dataNamesLike)
    ;

    data _null_;
      set dataNames;
      appendStep = "PROC APPEND BASE=&BASE DATA=&FROMLIB.." || trim(memname) || ";" ;
      call execute ('%NRSTR(' || trim(appendStep) || ')');

      maintenanceStep = "PROC DATASETS NOLIST; COPY IN=&FROMLIB OUT=&DONELIB MOVE; SELECT " || trim(memname) || '; QUIT;' ;
      call execute ('%NRSTR(' || trim(maintenanceStep) || ')');
    run;

    %let syslast = &BASE;
%mend;

%appendFromLib (
  base=HISTORY.COMPLETE_ALL
  fromLib=EXTRACT,
  dataNamesLike='completeextract%',
  doneLib=DONE
);
```

A further web search for *Proc APPEND* will likely find other examples and maybe some existing macro libraries containing this same functionality.

Comment: Thanks very much Richard! However, I just wanted to understand what is meant by extract datasets? is it the list of datasets that I am appending?

Comment: Sort of, but no not a list -- the macro discovers automatically the list using `dictionary.tables`.This answer presumes the  completeextract8634/8640/etc data sets are in one library, the permanent growing in another, and the place to move the appended data a third.  Your actual system or data management plans may be different -- such as deleting the extracts after appending, not growing a multi-month permanent table, etc....

Comment: And if I want to append few of the files, not all, then how do I put the filter?
'completeextract8634.sas7bdat'
'completeextract8640.sas7bdat'
'completeextract8641.sas7bdat' 
'completeextract8645.sas7bdat'and so on..
Let's say I need to append the first 3 files out of the list of 50 (say)?

Answer (score 1):

In response to the comment

You can change the macro definition to specify a default such as `dataNamesLike=%` and then add a new parameter `dataNamesWhere=1`.

The additional parameter can be used in the *dataNames* query to also have `and &dataNamesWhere`.  You would be responsible with coming up with a sufficiently robust where clause that performs the selection you want.

You could also add a parameter `dataNames=` that contains a premade list of data sets to process in the append/maintain manner. The default *discovery* step would be bypassed if this parameter is used.

Alternate code example

```
* make my own list of data sets to process;

%let names = ;
proc sql outobs=3;
  create table work.dataNamesX as
  select memname 
  from dictionary.tables
  where libname = "EXTRACT"
    and memname like "COMPLETEEXTRACT%"
  order by
    memname descending
  ;

%appendFromLib(base=here.biggun, fromLib=EXTRACT, dataNames=work.dataNamesX, doneLib=there);
```

**Updated macro**

```
%macro appendFromLib(base=, fromLIb=, dataNamesLike=%, doneLib=, dataNames=);
  proc sql;
    %if %length (&dataNames) = 0 %then %do;
      %let dataNames = work.dataNames;
      %if %sysfunc(exist(&dataNames)) %then %do;
        drop table &dataNames;
      %end;
      create table &dataNames as select
      memname from dictionary.tables
      where libname = "%upcase(&fromLib)"
        and memname like %upcase(&dataNamesLike)
      ;
    %end;

    data _null_;
      set dataNames;
      appendStep = "PROC APPEND BASE=&BASE DATA=&FROMLIB.." || trim(memname) || ";" ;
      call execute ('%NRSTR(' || trim(appendStep) || ')');

      maintenanceStep = "PROC DATASETS NOLIST; COPY IN=&FROMLIB OUT=&DONELIB MOVE; SELECT " || trim(memname) || '; QUIT;' ;
      call execute ('%NRSTR(' || trim(maintenanceStep) || ')');
    run;

    %let syslast = &BASE;
%mend;
```